# Android Single Layout to FIt All Screen Sizes

Tags: android, xml, layout, size, screen

I am updating my Android app and realized that I have created a layout for every possible screen size (layout-small, layout-large, etc...)  It would be a huge pain to go through every XML file and manually make a small change.  I am attempting to create a single XML file to support all screen sizes.  After reviewing the Android documentation and other questions on stackoverflow, it seems LinearLayout is the best choice as you can provide a weightSum and layout_weight for each item in the layout.  This is not working as expected (see below code and images).  I am doing this correctly?  Do I have to go back to creating a RelativeLayout for every possible screen size?

My images are an a single drawable folder and my layouts are in a single layout folder.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/key"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/image0_key" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Score: 0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Resulting View (overflow of items and layout not consistent for screen sizes)

Nexus One:

[image]

Tablet:

[image]

EDIT:
I have added the following drawable-____ folders.  It produces the same result.

[image]

Comment: The layout_height of each of the children should be 0dp because the height is calculated based upon the available space and distributed according to the weight. Your textview has a match_parent as well, that will force the tv to occupy as much space as the parent (the linear layout which is covering all the screen)

Comment: After changing the layout_height of each child to 0dp, nothing changes.  Looks exactly the same as above pictures.

Comment: You need to understand how weight works. Layout weight is distributed AFTER the layout is measured (in a second pass) so you have to provide images that have the same density in each display density, otherwise there's nothing to be done. The system uses the FREE space after the images have been placed.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying I need images for each density? (hdpi, mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi)

Comment: Yes, otherwise your images are always going to be the same size, and the only thing that changes is the "remaining" space after all the images have been placed.

Comment: I have added the drawable folders and nothing has changed.  It seems that some of the larger screens are not taking the weight value properly. See edit.

Comment: But apart from adding the folders, did you add the different sized assets into them? :)

Comment: Yes I created new images with the appropriate resolutions for each folder.

Comment: I changed the android:layout_width="match_parent" to wrap_content and now it seems to be working.  Now I just need the TextView to expand to fit its weight.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider creating compatibility layout folders. :)

[image]

Comment: That is what I am trying to cut out.  I want to only create one layout for every device so I don't have to edit all of them after making a small change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have a solution for the same by using android's percent layout we can now use `app:layout_heightPercent` and `app:layout_widthPercent` to fit all the screens using single layout.

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

Why use LinearLayout `weight` property now we have simpler solution.

> [Demo HERE !](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)
>
> [GitHub project HERE !](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)

Consider a simple sample

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Hope it's useful for someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below layout for arranging your ImageButton and TextView. It works for all screen size Layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageBtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageBtn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Score: 0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never put an weight sum like hundred ,just try using single digits

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetric dm =new DisplayMetric();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int h= dm.heightPixels;
int w= dm.widthPixels;
h=h/10; // 10 is for example for 10% of display height
w=((w*20)/100); // 20%of display width
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
YourObject.setLayoutParams(params);
```

//(YourObject) can be everything such as button , image button, textview,...

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here, one is to fill the size of the screen and the other is supporting the various resolution sizes of mobiles. Even within xxxhdpi, there are variations as new flagship Samsung Mobiles are drifting to 19.5 x 16.

Linear layout along with weight attributes does give a good coverage but beware of the nested tags and performance. It worked out well for most of the scenarios I have handled.

In addition, as pointed out in other answers, different drawables/resources for the standard sizes helps maintaining similar view in all devices.

[image]